# How to construct a SQL query to fetch different columns from same table in different rows?

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have a table in database like:
which contains some type along with their values that is different for every client and language:-

```
cname  | clang   | blogs | article| directory | video
John   | English | 4.5   | 4      | 5         | 10 
Jasmin | German  | 2     | 3      | 1.2       | 7
```

My Php page looks like this:-

Here I have used Two drop downs:

> |clientname|(/*First Drop Down to select Client Name*/)
>
> |clientlanguage|(/*Second To Select Language On the basis Of
>   clientname*/)

```
            Language
Blogs     | value  |
Article   | value  |
Directory | value  | 
Video     | value  |
```

just i need is how can i fetch these values from my table in this format using php and mysql only not even jquery

Comment: 1. See normalization. This IS the answer.

Comment: You want to change the value of the second `select` on the change of the first one, right? And you don't want to use any Javascript code? This is impossible!

Comment: i already have did that using java script, i am just trying to fetch the value in my table on the basis of the client name and language selected from dropdown

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries and PHP are server side communications and computations. It would be impossible to change the second dropdown after the first is chosen without using something like JS to communicate with the server once again and retrieve what you're looking for.

Are you simply asking how to a query for this:

```
SELECT blogs, article, directory, videos FROM tablename WHERE cname='clientname' AND clang='clientlanguage'
```

AND is used to select a row where BOTH parameters are met.

Comment: i already have did that using java script, i am just trying to fetch the value in my table on the basis of the client name and language selected from dropdown. i just need those values in the same pattern from my database.

Comment: i did that but how can i fetch all the values on change event without submitting button?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible without js. Once PHP sends out the page PHPs job is done and wont be able to change the website afterwards... but guess what? Thats the job of JS

Comment: i already have did that using java script, i am just trying to fetch the value in my table on the basis of the client name and language selected from dropdown. i just need those values in the same pattern from my database.

Comment: see the client name is selected from drop down and also the language is fetched on the basis of that clientname so now on the change event of language the values should be fetched and shown in below table. so how is it possible

Answer (score 0):

You can post a request to the same PHP page with the value of the first dropdown set to the selected value and populate the second one with the query result for the chosen value in the first dropdown. 
This PHP page will also contain the HTML UI embedded in it. This, however, is an ancient method to achieve the stated behaviour. You should consider using AJAX. It is very simple and straightforward to use.

For the query, you should do something like

```
select blogs, article, directory, video from table where cname="abc" and clan="English";
```

where abc is the value selected in the first dropdown and English is the value selected in the second dropdown

Comment: i have did that using ajax, dropdown actions are done client name is selected, language is fetched on the basis of client name, where i am having trouble is that how to fetch the values i.e explained as "value" above in my query, in the same pattern shown above from my database.

Comment: You should explain clearly what it is that you want. Give a good example.

Comment: sorry to trouble you but today is my first day on this site. actually the problem is with the pattern in which i have to fetch the values that i can not change as per the order, so i need to fetch the values from the database on the basis of the client name or id and the language selected with the change event of language.

Comment: Ok. So are you able to fetch the values from the database into the PHP? that is are you able to query the database and get the result? Just the result, not the pattern. And can you use JavaScript for querying?